# hg - Ignore directory at root only

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

In my project's `.hgignore`, I want to exclude `/static/` (i.e., the static folder at the root of the directory), but not `/templates/static/`. How would I configure `.hgignore` to allow this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried something like `syntax:regexp` with `^/static/.*`?

Comment: Can this be done with glob?

Comment: @buffer No. According to the [manpage](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html), a glob cannot be rooted. But you can switch between syntaxes within the `.hgignore`.

Comment: If you're using glob syntax by default in your .hgignore, you can use ```re:^static/``` to ignore the static folder only in your repo root.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can include `syntax: regexp` at the beginning of .hgignore and then use perl regex syntax to root a directory by using `^`. So just `^static` should do the work.

Comment: I would change that to `^static/`, otherwise it will ignore all directories whose name starts with static, which may cause confusion down the road.

Comment: If your `.hgignore` is in glob syntax you can just put `syntax: regexp` and `syntex: glob` before and after the line `^static/`. Apparently it's allowed to switch between syntaxes. See [manpage](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html): _"The chosen syntax stays in effect when parsing all patterns that follow, until another syntax is selected."_

Answer (score 2):

As of [Mercurial 4.9](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release4.9), you can use `syntax: rootglob` to insert rooted glob patterns.

> New rootglob: filename pattern for a glob that is rooted at the root of the repository. See hg help patterns and hg help hgignore for details