# Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2012 projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mercurial, hgignore

I currently use the answer to a similar question for [Visual Studio 2010](https://gist.github.com/4690206) as my go to hgignore file. Are there any notable additions to include with VS2012?

---

Below is a compiled list from many different sources. Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/4690206).

I have found that projects upgraded from VS2010 have a lot of backup and upgrade log files not required.

```
# use glob syntax
syntax: glob

*.obj
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.scc
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]humbs.db
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.resharper

# For projects upgraded from VS2010
[Bb]ackup/
_UpgradeReport_Files/
UpgradeLog.*

*.opensdf
*.sdf
ipch/
x64/
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

By pulling from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095696/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2010-projects/4095783#4095783) previous answer about Visual Studio 2010, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709422/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2012-projects/12719725#12719725) response in this question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709422/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2012-projects/12981198#comment20947977_12981198) wonderful citation I compiled this listing:

```
############################################################
## Visual Studio 2012
############################################################
syntax: glob

## User-specific files

*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

## Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

## MSTest test Results

[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.scc

## Visual C++ cache files

ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

## Visual Studio profiler

*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

## Guidance Automation Toolkit

*.gpState

## ReSharper Ignores

_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

## TeamCity Ignores
_TeamCity*

## DotCover Ignores

*.dotCover

## NCrunch Ignores

*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

## Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

## DocProject Ignores

DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

## Click-Once Ignores

publish/

## Publish Web Output

*.Publish.xml
*.pubxml

## Windows Azure Build Ignores

csx
*.build.csdef

## Windows Store Ignores

AppPackages/

## RIA/Silverlight projects

Generated_Code/

## SQL Server Ignores

App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

## Backup & Report Files when converting a solution
## Not required, we have mercurial!

_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

## NuGet
packages/

## Miscellaneous Ignores

sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

## Windows Ignores

$RECYCLE.BIN/
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
Desktop.ini
```

This is currently working great in my repositories.

Comment: There might be a number of lines to add from the "official" .gitignore file for Visual Studio (the formats looks very similar): https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: In fact if you compare them this is almost line for line the same (bar commenting differences etc) which would make sense as they are trying to do the same time! :)

Comment: Great stuff, for me it was only missing the packages folder for nuget (got restore enabled, no reason to push them), I also followed the */** comment from VS2010 question so it will not drop files beginning with folder names, although I never name files like that..

Comment: @JonathanLevison I just added it!

Comment: Warning: I found that some Debug subfolders of included third-party website tools were being unnecessarily excluded. Be aware that ignore entries can be rooted using regex e.g. `[Dd]ebug*/` will unnecessarily match every folder named Debug everywhere whereas `^[Bb]in/[Dd]ebug*/` will match the ASP.NET Debug folder.  See also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051190/hg-ignore-directory-at-root-only

Answer (score 2):

I generally build them as I go but this is a good starting point that I currently use for a fairly complex project.  The `ipch/` directory is the only new thing in VS2012.

```
ipch/
x64/
*Debug/
*Release/
TestResults/
*sdf
*.suo
*.user
```

`*Debug/` and `*Release` handle device drivers that target `Win7 Release`, for example.  There are `*.opensdf` and `*.sdf` files that can be listed separately if desired.