# How to add files in hgignore files with tortoisehg?

Tags: regex, tortoisehg, hgignore

In tortoisehg, i would like to add home/hello.php in .hgignore files but i don't know how to do this? It doesn't work. With somme regular expression?
I try home/hello.php in hgignore but it doesn't ignore anymore. Someone have idea?

Answer (score 1):

I use [glob syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) instead of regex because... well, regexes are scary demons. The following .hgignore file would ignore `home/hello.php`:

```
# use glob syntax
syntax: glob

# Project-specific files below here...
home/hello.php
```

You can find some fine examples of pre-made .hgignore files for common programming environments, such as this [Visual Studio one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709422/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2012-projects).