# Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2013 projects

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2013, mercurial, hgignore

As a followup to my question on [VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709422/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2012-projects), are there any addition that should be made to the `.hgignore` file for VS2013? Below is the previous answer.

```
############################################################
## Visual Studio 2012
############################################################
syntax: glob

## User-specific files

*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

## Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

## MSTest test Results

[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

## Visual C++ cache files

ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

## Visual Studio profiler

*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

## Guidance Automation Toolkit

*.gpState

## ReSharper Ignores

_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

## TeamCity Ignores
_TeamCity*

## DotCover Ignores

*.dotCover

## NCrunch Ignores

*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

## Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

## DocProject Ignores

DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

## Click-Once Ignores

publish/

## Publish Web Output

*.Publish.xml
*.pubxml

## Windows Azure Build Ignores

csx
*.build.csdef

## Windows Store Ignores

AppPackages/

## RIA/Silverlight projects

Generated_Code/

## SQL Server Ignores

App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

## Backup & Report Files when converting a solution
## Not required, we have mercurial!

_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

## NuGet
packages/

## Miscellaneous Ignores

sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings

## Windows Ignores

$RECYCLE.BIN/
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
Desktop.ini
```

Comment: FWIW, *.pubxml is designed to be checked in so publish settings can be shared across a team.

Comment: Some teams may wish to have developer-specific publishing profiles, however. For example, you don't necessarily want your production publishing profiles to be accessible to developers, depending on your organization's security practices.

Comment: This is not a copy/paste list, but rather an inclusive list from which people can choose what they need.

Comment: Both are fair points regarding `*.pubxml` of course.  In the end "[t]his is not a copy/paste list" is the key I think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By merging the `.hgignore` I use regularly (with VS 2013 Ultimate) and the `.hgignore` in your question I compiled the following:

```
############################################################
## Visual Studio 2013
############################################################
syntax: glob

## User-specific files

*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

## Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

## Roslyn cache directories

*.ide/

## MSTest test Results

[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

## NUnit

*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

## Build Results of an ATL Project

[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

## Chutzpah Test files

_Chutzpah*

## Visual C++ cache files

ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

## Visual Studio profiler

*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

## TFS 2012 Local Workspace

$tf/

## Guidance Automation Toolkit

*.gpState

## ReSharper Ignores

_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

## JustCode

.JustCode

## TeamCity Ignores

_TeamCity*

## DotCover Ignores

*.dotCover

## NCrunch Ignores

_NCrunch_*
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

## MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

## Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

## Installshield output folder

[Ee]xpress/

## DocProject Ignores

DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

## Click-Once Ignores

publish/

## Publish Web Output

*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
*.pubxml

## Windows Azure Build Ignores

csx/
*.build.csdef

## Windows Store Ignores

AppPackages/

## RIA/Silverlight projects

Generated_Code/

## SQL Server Ignores

App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

## Backup & Report Files when converting a solution
## Not required, we have mercurial!

_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

## NuGet
packages/

## Business Intelligence projects

*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

## Microsoft Fakes

FakesAssemblies/
*.favdoc

## Miscellaneous Ignores

sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/

## Windows Ignores

$RECYCLE.BIN/
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
Desktop.ini
```

Besides additions for a couple popular plugins (e.g. JustCode and NUnit), it also has additions for BI projects, Fakes etcetera.

You can see all the detailed differences if you just save the listing in your question, save the listing in my answer, and diff the two of course.