# Mercurial .hgignore for Visual Studio 2015 projects

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2015, mercurial, hgignore

This question has been asked for Visual Studio versions [2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34784/203705), [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4095696/203705), [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12709422/203705), and [2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22011316/203705), but alas, not yet for Visual Studio 2015.

How should I update the `.hgignore` file from [j0e3gan's answer to the 2013 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26951420/203705) of this question to properly handle Visual Studio 2015 projects?

As for what I've seen so far, it appears to be pretty good. I only needed to add the `.vs` directory to the `User-specific files` section, but I've not tested it on a wide range of project types.

It's always fairly easy to spot things which should be added to your ignore. Just run `hg stat` and if you see something you don't like, add it! With that in mind, I suppose my real question is, **is there anything from the VS 2013 ignore file below which can safely be removed for VS 2015?**

```
############################################################
## Visual Studio 2013
############################################################
syntax: glob

## User-specific files

*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

## Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
build/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

## Roslyn cache directories

*.ide/

## MSTest test Results

[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

## NUnit

*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml

## Build Results of an ATL Project

[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c

*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc

## Chutzpah Test files

_Chutzpah*

## Visual C++ cache files

ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

## Visual Studio profiler

*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

## TFS 2012 Local Workspace

$tf/

## Guidance Automation Toolkit

*.gpState

## ReSharper Ignores

_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user

## JustCode

.JustCode

## TeamCity Ignores

_TeamCity*

## DotCover Ignores

*.dotCover

## NCrunch Ignores

_NCrunch_*
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

## MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/

## Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/

## Installshield output folder

[Ee]xpress/

## DocProject Ignores

DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

## Click-Once Ignores

publish/

## Publish Web Output

*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
*.pubxml

## Windows Azure Build Ignores

csx/
*.build.csdef

## Windows Store Ignores

AppPackages/

## RIA/Silverlight projects

Generated_Code/

## SQL Server Ignores

App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf

## Backup & Report Files when converting a solution
## Not required, we have mercurial!

_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

## NuGet
packages/

## Business Intelligence projects

*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings

## Microsoft Fakes

FakesAssemblies/
*.favdoc

## Miscellaneous Ignores

sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
node_modules/

## Windows Ignores

$RECYCLE.BIN/
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
Desktop.ini
```

Comment: I suggest the easy way: create a trivial project (like hello.c) and find out.

Comment: I have done. I fully admit this is a "me too" question. I'll update the question to identify what I've found so far.

Comment: @planetmaker does my recent edit help?