# Mercurial .hgignore for umbraco 7 web project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mercurial, umbraco7, hgignore

I used the answer of the question for [Visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709422/mercurial-hgignore-for-visual-studio-2012-projects) as my .hgignore file before.

now I am developing an umbraco 7 project in Visual Studio. After changing a small thing, i found a lot of changed file showing in mercurial working directory. I understand as it is a CMS, it changes a lot of files internally. but it is very confusing to maintain.

what files should i place in the **.hgignore** file when using **umbraco 7 in VS2012**.

Comment: You should track those files which are important to your project and ignore those which are not and only personal editor settings

Answer (score 1):

Basically most of the items in the /App_Data/ folder, and possibly the /media/ folder if you don't want to keep track of that. Google for Umbraco .gitignore files and use those as a reference as well if you want a more comprehensive list.