# How to exclude path in root directory in .hgignore?

Tags: mercurial

For example, I have files structure:

```
app
- media
media
```

If I add line

```
media
```

to .hgignore, both folders (media, app/media) will be excluded. But I want to exclude only media folder from project root (./media). I need a solution, which will work in Linux and Windows.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051190/hg-ignore-directory-at-root-only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a regular expression (unless you've switched it to glob with `syntax: glob` in the file). Therefore, you can use `^` to match the start of the path (as it is inside the repository) and `$` to match the end.

```
^media$
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need and I put in the following in the ignore file:

```
^target/.*
/target/.*
```

The first entry will ignore the target dir in the root directory.
The second entry will ignore any target dir in inner directories.

Works well for us (both win and linux)

I hope this helps.

Comment: `/target/.*` will match a file in a directory `target` *anywhere in the repository*. The second one, using `^` to match start-of-path (regexp format), is what is wanted for this case.

Comment: The first is an example for excluding the "target" directory in inner folders.

Comment: You didn't *say* that. And that's not what he *asked* for.